# EF-generated SQL Server query optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I need to speed up this SQL query generated by EF.

```
SELECT TOP (10) 
    [Filter1].[ID1] AS [ID], 
    [Filter1].[TransactionDateTime] AS [TransactionDateTime], 
    [Filter1].[TransactionType] AS [TransactionType], 
    [Filter1].[OrganizationID] AS [OrganizationID], 
    [Filter1].[Amount] AS [Amount], 
    [Filter1].[Value] AS [Value], 
    [Filter1].[PackagingID] AS [PackagingID], 
    [Filter1].[PackagingTransaction_ID] AS [PackagingTransaction_ID]
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID1], 
         [Extent1].[TransactionDateTime] AS [TransactionDateTime], 
         [Extent1].[TransactionType] AS [TransactionType], 
         [Extent1].[PackagingID] AS [PackagingID], 
         [Extent1].[OrganizationID] AS [OrganizationID], 
         [Extent1].[Amount] AS [Amount], 
         [Extent1].[Value] AS [Value], 
         [Extent1].[PackagingTransaction_ID] AS [PackagingTransaction_ID], 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[TransactionDateTime] DESC, [Extent1].[ID] DESC) AS [row_number]
     FROM   
         [dbo].[LedgerTransaction] AS [Extent1]
     INNER JOIN 
         [dbo].[Organization] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[OrganizationID] = [Extent2].[ID]
                                           AND [Extent2].[OrganizationTypeCode] = 2) AS [Filter1]
WHERE 
    [Filter1].[row_number] > 0
ORDER BY 
    [Filter1].[TransactionDateTime] DESC, [Filter1].[ID1] DESC
```

Here is the database structure:

**Organization**:

```
ID  int Unchecked
ExternalID  int Unchecked
OrganizationTypeCode    tinyint Unchecked
Name    nvarchar(100)   Unchecked
Address nvarchar(50)    Checked
```

**LedgerTransaction**:

```
ID  int Unchecked
TransactionDateTime datetime    Unchecked
TransactionType tinyint Unchecked
PackagingID int Unchecked
OrganizationID  int Unchecked
Amount  int Unchecked
Value   decimal(19, 4)  Unchecked
```

Queries:

```
select count(*)
from LedgerTransaction

36529499


select count(*)
from Organization

17822
```

I tried

```
create index test_patrik
on Organization(Id, OrganizationTypeCode)
```

But that doesn't yield any improvement. Query takes about 34 seconds to run.

Comment: Create an index on LedgerTransaction(TransactionDateTime DESC, ID DESC)

Comment: Yeah that helped from 30sec to less then 1sec

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT TOP (10) . . .
FROM (SELECT . . . 
      FROM [dbo].[LedgerTransaction] AS [Extent1] INNER JOIN
           [dbo].[Organization] AS [Extent2]
           ON [Extent1].[OrganizationID] = [Extent2].[ID] AND
              [Extent2].[OrganizationTypeCode] = 2
     ) AS [Filter1]
WHERE [Filter1].[row_number] > 0
ORDER BY [Filter1].[TransactionDateTime] DESC, [Filter1].[ID1] DESC;
```

You can remove `row_number()` and the outer `WHERE` condition.  `row_number()` is always greater than 0, so this is redundant.

There is not much else you can do.  Start with indexes on `Organization(OrganizationTypeCode, ID)`, `LedgerTransaction(OrganizationID)`.

However, the outer `ORDER BY` is probably taking the bulk of the time and there is little you can do about that.